# Default update detailViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've created an app that allows users to add information (from an addViewController), which is then displayed in a UITableView on the rootViewController. When the user taps the tableViewCell the detailViewController then displays, you guessed it, more details regarding the inputted user information. What I'm trying to accomplish is to setup an editViewController that will allow users to edit information they've already submitted.

Currently, I'm trying to auto-populate the editViewController with the information that was previously submitted by the user (after which they can press save and update the info). However, I'm getting stuck trying to perform this auto-populating and I'm not sure this is even the best route to accomplish this.

Here is the edit method that is called to load the editViewController from the detailViewController.

```
-(IBAction)editDetails:(id)sender {

 editViewController *evc = [[editViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"editViewController" bundle:nil];
 rootViewController *rvc = [[rootViewController alloc] init];

 UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:evc];

    [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
 ///For Style
 NSInteger styleCount = [[rvc scoreTypeArray] count];

 NSInteger styleRows = [rvc.scoreTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; ///HERE I GET AN ERROR MESSAGE SAYING THAT indexPath IS NOT DEFINED

 ///For Date
 NSInteger count = [[rvc dateArray] count];
 NSInteger rows = [[rvc indexPath] row]; ///AND HERE I GET A WARNING MESSAGE SAYING rootViewController MAY NOT RESPOND TO INDEX PATH, AND OF COURSE IT DOESN'T WORK

 [[evc dateField] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[evc dateArray] objectAtIndex:(count-1-rows)]]];


 [[evc styleField] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[rvc scoresArray] objectAtIndex:(styleCount-1-styleRows)]]];

    [navigationController release];

 [evc release];
 [rvc release];}
```

So here I'm trying to load the information from a saved array that is declared in my rootViewController.

Any thoughts any body?

Answer (score 0):

Make propertyes in your edit view with retain, and then just edit the value. Retain just give you and reference to the original object. The setText on the text field just make an new copy of your string.
 If you want to do this approch you can make an delegate protocol in your Edit view and set the current navigation controller that presents your edit view to be the delegate of yor edit view. And in your edit view when he will dissapear call the delegate method.

Delegate doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

Declared property doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/DeclaredProperty.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH13-SW1)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

well...

```
NSInteger styleRows = [rvc.scoreTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This is wrong because, you are trying to access indexPath.row which is not defined within this method. IndexPath.row is usually used within the tableView's methods like

```
(tableView*)didSelectRowAt:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

So you will have to pass the value indexPath.row from the tableView's delegatemethods as a parameter in editDetails method.

but you actually dont need this... instead do this:

in `detailViewController` and `editViewController`, create a `NSString *dateObject` and make it of `@property(nonatomic,assign).`
Now in your root viewcontroller's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, when the user taps the row,

```
 [dvc setDateObject:self.dateArray objectAtindex:indexPath.row];
```

so now, the `detailViewController` contains a reference to the original date in the dateObject. any change you make here will also change the date in the rootViewController's dateArray.

So when the use taps the edit button, call the

```
-(IBAction)editDetails:(id)sender {

    editViewController *evc = [[editViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"editViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:evc];
    [evc setDateObject:self.dateObject];
    [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

    [navigationController release];
    [evc release];

}
```

Now you've again passed on the original dateObject to the editViewController. in its viewDidLoad, set the textField, and when the user edits and hits done, replace the dateObject in editViewController with the modified dateObject. Remember,this is the original dateObject that was passed as a reference from rootViewController. so you've replaced it there as well in rootViewController's dateArray. now you just need to know when you return from detailViewController to rootViewController and do a [table reloadData];

tadan!!!

Comment: When I build I get this warning. Things run but nothing passes from view to view and it eventually crashes. warning: 'detailViewController' may not respond to '-setDataObject:objectAtindex:'
(Messages without a matching method signature will be assumed to return 'id' and accept '...' as arguments).

Comment: I'm just having no luck with this. I cannot figure out how to add and replace the original array object from a string that is not declared in the same class. I can get the strings to update (my understanding is that each class has it's own string) but that in no way effects the objects in the array. Can you or anyone explain more how this works?? Thank you : )

Comment: Okay, are you defining a variable called dateObject in the header file? and its associated property? you should set the property as @property(nonatomic, assign)xxx dateObject; and also have a @synthesize dateObject in your .m file

Comment: there are two types of variables, retained and assigned. the retained one are pass-by-value. here you are giving each class a copy of the value of the dateObject, then when you have changed the value in the editViewController, you need to tell the detailed view controller that "Hey i've changed this value, and here it is" through a delegate. look what terentte posted ^^. The second kind of variables are assigned variables. This is what i was asking you to do. They are all pass-by-reference(weak linked). so even though editviewController has the dateObject it is only a pointer that...

Comment: ... points to the actual string dateObject which is in the rootviewcontroller's array. this same dateObject is used by detailViewController as well. So when you edit it, and go back, detailViewController will also display the changed value if you refresh the view